# Is shared memory model a process violation?

Tags: shared-memory

Two processes trying to access a memory(shared region of RAM for IPC) outside of either of the processes(or both), is it a process violation ?

Comment: Define your terms, please. What is your definition of "process violation"?

Comment: A process trying to access a region of memory outside of it's address space...access violation.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified the OS and language.

In general shared memory is not outside of the processes address spaces, but rather - it exists in *both* address spaces. The OS takes care of that.

Comment: consider...
1. Windows OS and C#
2. Ubuntu OS and C++ . Can you be a little more specific about how the OS takes care of that?

Comment: Shared memory in C# is a problem. You need to resort to unsafe code, and do some juggling to get it to work right. Most likely you'll end up doing a lot of marshaling to managed objects, and lose the advantage of shared memory. Better let WCF take care of IPC.